# Modifying a for loop in a string

Tags: javascript

I have string it contains some code. I want to make some changes on it. There is a for loop I want to modify with js.
The loop:

```
"for i in 0..10 loop"
```

I want it to be:

```
"for (var i=0; i<10; i++)"
```

It sounds me very complicated. What should be the easiest approach?

Comment: Should this for loop be executing? Why is it in a string?

Comment: Not really complicated, assuming the pattern is fixed - **for** [name of variable] **in** [start index] **..** [end index] **loop** - bolded are the fixed words. If this is the case just split by space and take the stuff you need.

Comment: No its not executing. I'm tring to convert the code to js.

Comment: Wouldn't `0..10` need `i<=10` in JS? (Or am I misinterpreting the starting language?)

Comment: That's how I read it too, and how my initial answer was written, but to each his own I guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a way to do it, but probably not the best:

```
var str = "for i in 0..10 loop",
    str = str.replace("i in ", "(var i="),
    str = str.replace("..", "; i<"),
    str = str.replace(" loop", "; i++)");
console.log(str);
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/purmou/fBsqU/).

Answer (score 2):

Based on my comment here is simple implementation:

```
var before = "for i in 0..10 loop";
var after = Translate(before);

function Translate(command) {
    var tokens = command.split(" ");
    if (tokens.length != 5)
        return "ERROR: invalid command (wrong number of tokens)";
    if (tokens[0] != "for" || tokens[2] != "in" || tokens[4] != "loop")
        return "ERROR: invalid command (syntax error)";
    var indices = tokens[3].split("..");
    if (indices.length != 2)
        return "ERROR: invalid command (invalid indices format)";
    var startIndex = parseInt(indices[0], 10);
    var endIndex = parseInt(indices[1], 10);
    if (isNaN(startIndex) || isNaN(endIndex))
        return "ERROR: invalid command (illegal indices)";
    var varName = tokens[1];
    return "for (var " + varName + "=" + startIndex + "; " + varName + "<" + endIndex + "; " + varName + "++)";
}
```

[Live test case](http://jsfiddle.net/yahavbr/6auV8/).

It's not perfect, for example you can further check the variable name is legal i.e. start with English letter, not a reserved word etc.

Answer (score 2):

You can use regex matching to pull out the parts you are interested in.

```
var string_to_match = 'for i in 0..10 loop',
    re = /for ([A-z]*) in (\d*)\.\.(\d*) loop/,
    data = re.exec(string_to_match);

// data contains:
// ["for i in 0..10 loop", "i", "0", "10"]

for(i = data[2]; i < data[3]; i++) {
    console.log(i);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to match this regular expression `^for (.+) in (\d+)\.\.(\d+) loop$` and replace with `for (var \1=\2; \1 < \3; \1++)`.

Try it on http://www.solmetra.com/scripts/regex/ for example...